# splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Is it true that the splitting field for $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ where $\xi_n$ is a primitive n$^{th}$ root of unity, making it an extension of degree $\phi(n)$ (Euler phi function)? Every element of this extension should look like $\sum a_k\xi_n^k$?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.

Comment: It’s true, but part of the proof is rather advanced, namely the proof that the degree of the extension is no smaller than $\phi(n)$. This is equivalent to the $\Bbb Q$-irreducibility of the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(X)$. In case $n$ is a prime power, the proof is not at all hard, but when $n$ is divisible by two odd primes, or $4$ and an odd prime, things get sticky.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything you said is true. I have only added that the $a_k$ should be elements in $\mathbb Q$. These fields are known as the [Ciclotomic Fields.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field)

Comment: Actually, these fields are rather known as ["Cyclotomic fields"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field).